# Slaman and Woodin on Mathematical logic

Tags: bibliography, reference-request, lo.logic

At the references section of the wikipedia article for Definable set, one finds the following entry:

Slaman, Theodore A. and W. Hugh Woodin. Mathematical Logic: The Berkeley Undergraduate Course. Spring 2006.

What kind of material is it? Manuscripted lecture notes? Is it available somehow? I'm highly curious about its content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the notes I have is from 2006, they are organized in the form of a short book. It is my understanding they have been updated since, and I believe the current version has new material on model theory, computability, and incompleteness. In particular, I think that Woodin's proof of the second incompleteness theorem for set theory, that I have covered [elsewhere](http://caicedoteaching.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/woodins-proof-of-the-second-incompleteness-theorem-for-set-theory/), is discussed there.

I think that the notes are distributed to the students at Berkeley that take the course, usually taught by Ted or Hugh, but I do not know whether they plan to publish them, and I am not sure they want to disseminate them otherwise.

The table of contents of the version I have is as follows:

- Propositional logic
- First order logic: syntax
- First order logic: semantics
- The logic of first order structures
- Gödel's Completeness Theorem
- The Compactness Theorem
- More on the logic of structures

To give an idea of the content, the languages that are discussed are finite (or recursive), and set theoretical prerequisites are kept at a minimum. This simplifies the discussion of some key results (such as compactness or the Löwenheim-Skolem theorems). Besides what I have already mentioned, topics covered include elimination of quantifiers, model completeness, Presburger arithmetic, and a study of definability for particular structures.

I would expect that contacting Ted or Hugh directly is the best way to obtain a copy of the notes.

Comment: It looks like it is that study of definability what motivated its inclusion among the references for the article I mentioned in my question. Thank you very much.